# restart Sphinx from php

Tags: php, linux, bash, sphinx

Can anybody help me? I'm using sphinx searcher, but i have many databases. I dynamically controll them (change the sphinx config file ), but after i add an index to the config file sphinx needs to be restarted. I have created an bash script for doing this (stop shpinx, start it, indexer --rotate --all ) and when i run the script from terminal it is ok, but when i run from apache server it is not working. How can i do this without changenig the owner of the apache server to root ( it will decrease the security of my server )?

Comment: 1) setuid 2) run the script from cron, and check (eg: the database / fs) that there is restart needed  BTW why do you change the config file?

Comment: because for each database, i add into config file an source with ip of db, db_user, db_pass, db_name and for this source i add an indexer. 
When i try to use the added indexer in php it doesnt recognize the new added indexer without restarting sphinx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i do this without changenig the owner of the apache server to root

How about sudo? Put something like this in your sudoers...

```
apache ALL= NOPASSWD: /path/to/script command
```

The catch is to make sure that the script cannot be exploited... as it is running as root... ie is read-only + exec for apache, ensure that commands/switches you send to the script are sanity checked.

I hope that helps,
Kind Regards,
Nick

Comment: I was trying sudo without adding 
`apache ALL= NOPASSWD: /path/to/script command` 
script and it wasn't working. 
Now it's OK. Thnx for the help...

Comment: Hi Denis, Could you tell me which command you had use as I am having the same difficulty to running indexer in the cron job.